# Uploading to FTP server with as many threads as possible

Tags: windows, multithreading, command-line, ftp

This might sound like a strange request, but I'm hoping I have more luck here than I've had googling for the same topic.

I'm searching for a Windows based application that allows me to upload files to an FTP server via the command line, across as many threads as possible.

I'm currently trialing WinSCP, which has a simple scripting interface, that I can invoke from the command line. However, whilst it's a) windows based, b) command line driven/scriptable it doesn't make use of any multi threading to synchronise uploads of large files.

It seems I'm forever limited to achieving 2 of my 3 goals. For example, FileZilla is a) windows based and b) multithreaded for uploads, but unfortunately lacks any command line or scripting capabilities :/

Does anyone know of anything that might be able to achieve all 3 of my desires?

Comment: To take a step back: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with "as many threads as possible"? I'd guess that threading is not the bottleneck of most **network** oriented systems.

Comment: Well the threading is the trick that FileZilla uses to achieve it's higher speeds. Many open upload threads, transferring as much data as they can until either your output, or the server's input is maxed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/sourcecode.php) is GPL, so you could fork it and create a command-line/scriptable version sans the GUI. You'd have to implement the scripting engine though.

Alternately, you could implement a client on top of [Twisted FTP](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.1.0/api/twisted.protocols.ftp.html) (in Python).